# Lengthy core-data delete run in background/foreground mode

Tags: ios, multithreading, core-data, grand-central-dispatch

I have a VERY lengthy core-data delete task of 92k some-odd records which takes a really long time to run.  Initially it was locking up the UI thread so I attempted to stick the call on a background thread.  What I noticed, in the simulator, however, is that when I background the app this task stops running.

I'm wondering if there is a quick tweak I can make the the code so my delete will continue running once the application has been backgrounded for the 10 minutes or however long they are allowed to run.

When I start up my class I make a background queue:

```
backgroundQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, nil);
```

Then when its time to delete my objects

```
- (void)queueForDelete:(FlightRecording *)flight {

    NSError *error = nil;
    flight.deleteFlagValue = 1;
    [managedObjectContext save:&error];

    // Remove flights form Internal table dataStructure
    [flightList removeObjectAtIndex:[tmpIndexPath row]];
    [[self tableView] deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[tmpIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

    //Queue flight for deletion in the background
    dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, ^{
        NSLog(@"Adding %@ to deletion Queue", flight.getFileName);
        [self deleteFlight:flight];
    });
    [[self tableView] reloadData];
}
```

This code did make the UI more responsive but it still takes about 5 minutes - 10 minutes (in the simulator) to delete my objects.  I would like the user to be able to background the app and have the delete process still running because regardless of background/foreground it does have an impact on the responsiveness of the application.

Comment: Just an observation - since you are calling `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths` there is no need to call `reloadData`

Answer (score 0):

Do this task within an `NSManagedObjectContext` `-performBlock:` call. Do it on a child context with private queue concurrency type. That will give you asynchronous processing.

Don't save your context on each call.

Don't update your tableview (`reloadData`, `delteRowsAtIndexPaths`) on each call. This is a Model task. Don't update the UI.

Your use of `tmpIndexPath` is a code smell. That's another sign of mixing Model tasks with View tasks. Deleting a bunch of objects is purely a Model task. Write the code such that no UI or Controller is assumed to exist.

Comment: Would that be a single child context per record begin deleted?  Or a child single child context that I keep tossing preformBlocks on?

Comment: Neither. But you're close. Make a child context. Send it a -performBlock that will iterate over all the objects to be deleted, and delete them. At the end of that block, save your child context. Check the result (it will probably succeed, barring external mistakes). Within the block, just before it ends, enqueue a call (async) on the main thread to tell the main thread it's ok to update UI.

Comment: Also with regards to tmpIndexPath => What I did was separate the model from the core-data so I am manually generating a data-model into an array instead of dealing with the fetchedResultsController.  tmpIndexPath is to update the "ready for delete" flag in the objects so when i regenerate the model they get left out